React Native App Hangs on iOS When Clicking "No" Button in Modal but the same function works in Android
I'm working on a React Native application where users can respond to questions in a modal. The app works perfectly on Android, but it hangs on iOS when I click the "No" button.
When the "No" button is pressed, the Failed function is called, which updates the state and opens a modal. This works fine on Android but causes the app to hang on iOS.
Below are the relevant parts of my code:


Failed Function
The function triggered when the "No" button is pressed:
////////////////
const Failed = () => {
  const data = {
    habitId: routeData?._id,
    responseType: 'FALSE',
  };
  actions
    .UpdateHabit(data)
    .then(res => {
      setResponseData(res);
      routeData = res;
      listHabit();
      refsheet?.current?.close();
      setIsModalVisible(true);
      setShowColor('RED');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error, 'Error in Failed function');
    });
};

////////////
main_off_btns View
The view containing the "No" button:


<View style={styles.main_off_btns}>
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={Failed}
    style={styles.noButton}>
    <Text style={styles.Btn_text}>{'No'}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => Success()}
    style={{...styles.box_btn, backgroundColor: colors._B1DC00}}>
    <Text style={{...styles.Btn_text, color: colors._020202}}>
      Yes
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>


isModalVisible State
The modal visibility state:


const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

/////////
Modal View
The modal view that is displayed:


<Modal
  animationType="slide"
  transparent={true}
  visible={isModalVisible}
  onRequestClose={toggleModal}>
  <View style={styles.modalBackground}>
    <View style={styles.modalContent}>
      {showColor == 'RED' ? (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.delet_red_text}>
            {getFailureMessage(routeData?.tags, routeData?.levels)}
          </Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.delet_msg_text}>
          Y tomorrow to continue your journey.
        </Text>
      )}
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.OkButton}
        onPress={redirectMatch}>
        <Text style={{...commonStyles.fontBold15, color: 'black'}}>
          Close
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
</Modal>




iOS is not good with multiple modals.I see that in Failed function you are closing one and opening another modal. add a delay between them and try again.
Close a modal, add delay, open another modal.

Thanks a lot mate , this solution worked
